# Тип связи управление

Tags: управление

Хотел бы получить квалифицированную(конечно, по возможности) помощь.

Нужно в предложении найти словосочетание со связью УПРАВЛЕНИЕ: "Всякое бывало, но в памяти остался солнечный свет, который потом уже никогда не был так ярок"

На экзамене написал "в памяти свет" (по правилам писал в бланк слитно), по результатам это неверный ответ. А какой правильно и почему не мой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ: остался в памяти , где главное слово "остался" управляет падежом зависимого. Ваш ответ "в памяти свет" неверен, потому что это не словосочетание, а просто рядом расположенные слова, от одного слова к другому нельзя задать вопрос, поэтому они не составляют словосочетания.Если Вас устроил мой ответ, кликните, чтобы принять его

Comment: Можно же задать вопрос: свет (в чем?) в памяти?

Answer (score 1):

"В памяти остался солнечный свет". Это ГЛАГОЛЬНОЕ управление: остался (в чём?) в памяти.

Но ИМЕННОЕ словосочетание "свет (в чем?) в памяти" также возможно, не стоит утверждать, что эти слова никак не связаны.

В подобных случаях говорят  о том, что существительное "свет" приобретает способность управлять падежом, участвуя в реализации глагольных связей. В то же время такое именное словосочетание мы выделяем только ПРИ ОТСУТСТВИИ глагола "остался", например: "Этот солнечный свет в памяти помнился долго".

Здесь нельзя сказать: "помнился в памяти", поэтому "свет в памяти" - это связь управления, главным словом является существительное.

Comment: Может быть, в другом контексте.

Comment: Я уже, конечно, порядком запутался. Но я согласен с вами, а вот на егэ не засчитали.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Виктором, здесь связь управления  "остался в памяти''. Как правильно отметил Виктор, здесь слово "остался" управляет падежом зависимого. 
Дополнение. Здесь подробно все написано. http://www.babyblog.ru/community/post/russian/583037

Comment: Все равно странно. Разве не должно выполняться то, что словосочетание может переходить из падежа в падеж. Как сделать это словосочетание в именительном или творительном падеже?

Answer (score 0):

Если я ничего не путаю, с/соч. с управлением можно заменить на синонимичное с согласованием:дом из камня = каменный дом; брюки в полоску = полосатые брюки.

Comment: ну что ж, понятно. Спасибо.